# PHP removes backslash characters from JSON

Tags: php, json

PHP removes all backslash characters from JSON when saving it to DB. I don'y correctly identified the problem. How to get rid off this problem? I want to save the JSON as it provided to PHP?

Comment: Are you sure it is PHP removing the slashes? Have you checked the data in something that can peek at the HTTP request (such as Firebug)? Have you echoed it out from PHP to make sure it isn't being removed by the database insert? You need to track it through each step and find out exactly where it is being modified, and show us the code that is doing so.

Comment: @David I copied first segment of code from Firebug and second segment of code from database(phpmyadmin) directly.I am also confused.Please give me some solution.

Comment: I told you - you need to trace through your program and find out where the slashes are being lost. Knowing that the right data is sent to PHP but that it breaks it before inserting it into the database doesn't help identify which bit of PHP is breaking it.

Comment: @David I send the data to php via post method and the post method causing no problem.So I think it breaks when inserting into database using mysql query.So is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's PHP that is removing the backslashes? I rather think that:

- your first code is JavaScript code and the backslashes are stripped by the JS engine (try using single quotes for the whole string or use double backslashes).
- or you're storing the string to the database without adding escape characters (`mysql_real_escape_string`).

Answer (score 1):

simply u can put one more `\` before `\`